# What settings can be made in VisualStudio that affect all applications?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Please help.
Here is the situation.
I have a C++/C application. I need to compile all 4 configurations (x86 debug and release, x64 debug and release).
At some point, both (D and R) x64 configurations were compiling and running ok.  Then I switched over to try to compile the x86 versions (D & R).

When I tried to compile x86 D version, I got some warnings about not to use sprintf because it was not secure, use sprintf_s instead.  So I started changing my variables, including _splitpath into _splitpath_s.  However, I started getting some compile errors with my changes, so I decided to undo my changes and disable the warning instead (as suggested by the warning itself).

Once I did that, I started getting the errors below about _splitpath.
I didn't know what was going on anymore, so I decided to just remove the current version and start from scratch with a backup copy I had from another delivery.

I was shocked when I started getting the same _splitpath errors.  THat backup folder was fully functional, I don't understand why now it cannot compile.

I must have changed some settings in Visual Studio that are now affecting any version I try to compile, even older versions I run successfully in the past.

Can anybody take a look at the errors below and shed some light?  excerpts of my code are aldo provided below.
Any help will be immenselly appreciated.

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: SBF_Comm, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Deleting intermediate and output files for project 'SBF_Comm', configuration 'Debug|x64'
1>Compiling...
1>StdAfx.cpp
1>SBF_RS232.cpp
1>SBF_PleoraComm.cpp
1>SBF_NullComm.cpp
1>SBF_ImperxComm.cpp
1>SBF_HostComm.cpp
1>SBF_EDTComm.cpp
1>.\SBF_RS232.cpp(90) : error C2660: '_splitpath' : function does not take 5 arguments
1>.\SBF_RS232.cpp(178) : error C2660: '_splitpath' : function does not take 5 arguments
1>.\SBF_RS232.cpp(270) : error C2660: '_splitpath' : function does not take 5 arguments
1>.\SBF_RS232.cpp(417) : error C2660: '_splitpath' : function does not take 5 arguments
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\WinIRDir\WinIR3\SBF_Comm\x64\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>SBF_Comm - 4 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Below are 2 examples of how the _splitpath is being called.
This code has never been modified, and was compiling ok for years, now they generate the 2 first errors above.
I belive it could be due to a setting I must have changed in VisualStudio accidentally.
Any ideas of what it was?

```
//  LogFileClear:
static int nCommPort = -1;
char szModuleFileName[MAX_PATH+1],szDrive[_MAX_DRIVE+1],szDir[_MAX_DIR+1],szFile[_MAX_FNAME+1],szExt[_MAX_EXT+1];
GetModuleFileName(NULL,szModuleFileName,MAX_PATH+1);
_splitpath(szModuleFileName,szDrive,szDir,szFile,szExt);
sprintf(szFile,"CommLog%d",m_nCommPort);
_makepath(m_szCommLog,szDrive,szDir,szFile,"txt");


char szModuleFileName[MAX_PATH+1],szDrive[_MAX_DRIVE+1],szDir[_MAX_DIR+1],szFile[_MAX_FNAME+1],szExt[_MAX_EXT+1];
GetModuleFileName(NULL,szModuleFileName,MAX_PATH+1);
_splitpath(szModuleFileName,szDrive,szDir,szFile,szExt);
sprintf(szFile,"CommLog%d",m_nCommPort);
_makepath(m_szCommLog,szDrive,szDir,szFile,"txt");
```

Comment: Why don't you right-click one of the `_splitpath` calls in your code and select "Go to definition". That may tell you why it doesn't like your calls with 5 args.

Comment: Are you including `stdlib.h` or `cstdlib`?

Comment: I didn't realize that I wasn't logged in, so I had to respond with an "answer".  Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

Looking carefully to the snipet of code from my stdlib.h I posted above, I noticed that it had been changed (most likely accidentally).  The second and third instances of _splitpath had been swapped.
As soon as I swapped them back, recompiled and all went back to normal.
I think it is a good idea to set those included files to "ready only", to avoid accidents on "massive changes".
Thank you all for your hints, especially to Jim Rhodes for pointing out to the right direction.

Comment: These files are usually locates somewhere in Program Files, so I would assume these are effectively read only (as a write would need admin rights). Surely you're not running VS as admin?

Comment: I always have admin rights on my dev. machine, but running a search on stdlib.h showed 6 different versions of it at different places (I believe all within Program Files). Only one of them was set to read only (obviously not the one I'm using).  I just did a test on a text file setup as read-only, and eventhough I have admin rights I still could not save the file, I get the "save-as" dialog instead.

Comment: that's exactly what's supposed to happen. I don't see why an additional read only marking will enhance that non-editability.